# Determine if varname is a factor variable or not

Tags: stata

In a Stata program I'm creating, I need to know whether a program parameter is a factor variable or not.

```
program define my_program, rclass

    syntax varname(fv)

    if ... {
        display "`varlist' is a factor variable"
    } else {
        display "`varlist' is NOT a factor variable"
    }

    ...

end

my_program age
my_program i.gender
```

How could I write the if condition to make this work? I would prefer to get this working without checking if varname begins with "i.". Stata knows whether it's a factor variable or not since Stata offers the "fv" option (ie. varname(fv)). So how can I tap into the functionality built into Stata to determine this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am embarrassed by the code shown below, but it does point a direction to a solution for you, by comparing the results of `unab` and `fvunab` applied to your variable list.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. capture unab mac_unab : i.foreign

. display _rc
101

. capture fvunab mac_unab : i.foreign

. display _rc
0

. capture tsunab mac_unab : i.foreign

. display _rc
101

.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that **syntax** returns a macro **s(fvops)**, "which will be equal to 'true' when factor variables are specified and empty otherwise."
(http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/factor-variable-support/)

Therefore, I'm able to achieve what I wanted with the following code:

```
program define is_categorical, rclass

    syntax varname(fv)

    return scalar is_categorical = ("`s(fvops)'" == "true")

end

is_categorical i.education_level
```